# expandoobject not mapping correctly

Tags: c#, expandoobject

I have dynamic content that I want to map to subscriberattributes but when using ExpandoObject it created arrays with key value:

contractatrributes - subscriberattributes - 0 - key: "FirstName"- value "John"

assigning firstname of John in C#

```
etms.To.ContactAttributes.SubscriberAttributes.ApplicantName = "John";
```

in json

```
"ContactAttributes":{"SubscriberAttributes":[{"Key":"ApplicantName","Value":"John"}]}}


public class ContactAttributes
{
       // public SubscriberAttributes SubscriberAttributes { get; set; }
       public dynamic SubscriberAttributes { get; set; }
       public ContactAttributes()
       {
           SubscriberAttributes = new ExpandoObject();
       }
}
```

i want it to be like
contractattributes - subscriberattributes - FirstName - "John"
old code:

```
 public class ContactAttributes
 {
     public SubscriberAttributes SubscriberAttributes { get; set; }
     public ContactAttributes()
     {
         SubscriberAttributes = new SubscriberAttributes(); 
     }
}
public class SubscriberAttributes
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

in json

```
"ContactAttributes":{"SubscriberAttributes":{"FirstName":"John"}}
```

I can't hardcode firstname it could be many things.  I am using JSSerialize on object to send request so it has to match old format.

Comment: Could you please show us the JSON you are mapping into the dynamic property?

Comment: `it created arrays with key value` Can you show us the code you used to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I needed JsonConvert.SerializeObject works with expandoobject